# How to get around this ScriptUI bug in Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

When creating an UI list with an image in Illustrator .jsx using snippet bellow, image does not get displayed until user clicks/scrolls on the list. Is there a way (or hack around) to force image to display instantly?

```
var img="\u0089PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x06\b\x06\x00\x00\x00\u00E0\u00CC\u00EFH\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00Adobe ImageReadyq\u00C9e<\x00\x00\x00GIDATx\u00DAb\u00FC\u00FF\u00FF?\u00C3\u00DFk'\n\u00FF\x7Fz\x17\u00CB\x00\x04\u008C|B\u008B\u0099\u00B5,\u00FA\x19\u00FF\\=\x0E\x17\u0084\x01\u0090$\u00E3\u00EF\u00E3[\u00CF1`\x01L\f8\x00\x13H\x1B\u00BA H\u008C\tl\x11\u0092$\u00CCr\u0080\x00\x03\x00\u00F5\x0B\x1AM\u00A1{<Q\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\u00AEB`\u0082";

var w = new Window("dialog");
var list = w.add("listbox", undefined,["item0","item1"]);
list.items[0].image = ScriptUI.newImage(img);
w.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a feedback. In CS6 it looks like this:

[image]

It seems it works correct in CS6. I can't try this in CC right now. But I believe it can work different (or doesn't work at all) in CC. Unfortunately Illustrator's JS engine is a quite buggy beast.